# Trouble with sort function replacing values

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm just learning c++, and I've come to my first problem. I'm using visual studio and c++11. this is the code:

```
cout << "Enter 5 numbers to add." << endl;
for (int i(0); i < 5; ++i) {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    intList.push_back(x);
}
for (int item:intList) {
    sort(begin(intList), end(intList));
    cout << item << " ";
    total += item;
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Your total is " << total << endl;
```

As you can tell, it ask you to input 5 number and it adds them up. When I use cout, it output the contents of the vector correctly. As soon as I added the sort line, I had problems. It sorts the vector correctly, except it replaces the lowest value with the first value, even though it places it in the correct order. Example:

`Enter 5 numbers to add.
87 95 61 43 2
87 43 61 87 95
Your total is 373`

Also an additional question, is using `item::intList` the best/efficient way to iterate a vector. 
I'm sure this is an obvious solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reposition the call to sort so that it's outside the for loop.

Currently your sort is invalidating the iterator (on its first call as thereafter it's a no-op) which is causing the effect you observe.

(I'm sure you know that you don't need to sort the vector in order to compute the total.)

Comment: That work! I'm a little unclear on invalidating the iterator and why it only affects the first value of the sort.

Comment: I'm only sorting because I want to learn vectors. Having errors like this helps me to learn.

Comment: Essentially subsequent sorts will have no effect. And do google 'iterator invalidation'.

Comment: It only affects the first value of the sort because it is undefined behavior. A bug.

Comment: It's basically calling the first value of the vector then sorting the rest?

Comment: @John Sorting itself goes through a looping process to position the values in the right order.  Calling `sort` within another loop that goes over the same sequence you're sorting doesn't make a lot of sense.  It should only make you dizzy.

Comment: No. A b.u.g. "Undefined behavior" means any one of: your program producs correct results; it produced wrong results; all life as you know it coming to an end, and all molecules in your body exploding at the speed of light.

Comment: So there is no real explanation, except I made the computer dizzy? HAHA,  I like that. Thanks guys for all the help.

Comment: @samvarshavchik: I wonder if a call to a no-op sort is UB? One for the pub perhaps? I'm in the back of a taxi so can't check. The first sort invalidates the iterator but what about the subsequent calls? I wonder what the standard says.

Comment: I like how even in the back of a taxi, you're thinking about coding.